# Major notation doubt in calculus.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

Which of the following notations is correct?

$$\frac{d}{dx}(y)$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx}.$$

Please don't think this is trivial.

Comment: Both notation can be used $\frac{d}{dx}y$ or $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: The only difference is that you often see $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\text{some complicated expression})$, but less often $\dfrac{d(\text{some complicated expression})}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct, and they mean the same thing. If there is any difference, it's in the mind set they convey.

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a function defined as the derivative of $y$. It's a single symbol. On the other hand, $\frac d{dx}y$ is the result of applying the *differentiation operator* to the function $y$. It's two symbols (one function, one operator).

Comment: Is it correct to do the following:. d2x/dy2=d(dx)/(dy*dy) and then use the two dx's seperately further in the question?

Answer (score 2):

Both the notations are correct. Both of them mean the derivative of $y$ w.r.t $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Here some background:

On one hand, you can see the differentiation as a linear operator acting on functions. So, you may see $\frac{d}{dx}$ as a mapping that assigns to a (differentiable) function its derivative. Hence, you may write
$$\frac{d}{dx}y$$

Another way to see it, is to interpret the limit of the difference quotient as a quotient of "infinitesimally" small differences, which are called differentials. So, you may write 
$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Comment: By your explanation is it correct to do the following:.   d2x/dy2=d(dx)/(dy*dy)

Comment: @Aman: Yes. And this makes totally sense. Just check the paragraph on higher differntials on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function

Comment: But doesn't that mean (d/dx)y is incorrect?

Comment: No, you just exchanged the roles of $x$ and $y$.  you can differentiate also a function $x= x(y)$ with respect to $y$. Then in the symbols and interpretations the roles of $x$ and $y$ are exchanged.